# Writing android app parts in assembly

Tags: android, c++, assembly, arm, marmalade

I am using Marmalde and C/C++ to write an game for android.
Now I eant to write some important parts in assembler to improve the performance.
**But I am wondering me whether this app could run on the most android devices? (about 90%)**
Because in general assembler code depends on the processor and different android phones may have different processors, for example Intel or ARM, so I would have to write these parts in different assembler languages for every different processor!?

Comment: In most cases humans can't write better asm than the compiler/optimizer. So in general you should just stay away from writing asm yourself. You are likely to produce worse code and more problems than if you just leave it to the tools. (Warning: Egos may interfere).

Comment: Misguided attempt. You will not write better ASM than compiler.

Comment: **Probably** misguided.   You can beat a compiler for very specific pieces of code (audio mixing and filters come to mind), but overall, it's generally not worth it.

Comment: Thanks, but this was not actually my question. I want to know whether I would have to write the assembly code for every processor(Intel, ARM...) again?

Comment: Yes is the answer.   Assembly maps (very very very) very closely to the instruction set, and the ARM and x86 instruction sets are very different.  While it might be an interesting idea to have a simplistic assembly that maps to different ISAs, it doesn't sound like it'll really be useful because at that point, all you're making is a crappy language, rather than getting close to the metal so you can do things that can't be well expressed in a high level language with the instructions available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **of course you will have to write the assembly code for every <s>processor</s> ABI**.

The Android NDK has [specific support for different ABIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html).

Keep in mind that, while there are currently only three processor families supported (Intel x86/64, ARM and MIPS) you have to target all the different ABIs not the processors families themselves.

You can drop MIPS devices safely, they are very rare.
Intel devices are mostly tablet, but there are some phone too.
The vast majority of devices out there is ARM.

If you look at an official [optimization guide from ARM v8](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.uan0015b/Cortex_A57_Software_Optimization_Guide_external.pdf) or at a very useful [optimization guide for Intel](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) you can see that **it actually will take some time to write good assembly code**, it's not just about making something work (which you should already be able to do easily).

**Hint**
Write first the critical parts in C++, then look at the disassembly and see if you can do better or if you can recognize some sub-optimal patterns.
Only then rewrite the code in assembly.

Also before doing such micro-optimizations, try to use better data structures, better algorithms and better resource handling.

Comment: The last statement is absolute spot on and sums it all up!